# How do I render the contents of a variable in an ejs template?

Tags: html, express, ejs

I have an ejs template that should greet the user by calling their name when the page loads, however it does not display anything! Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>quotes</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">;
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/profile.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="title">profile</h1>
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout">logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            // not displaying user here
            <h1 class="greeting">Welcome <% user %></h1>
            <form action="/quotes" method="POST" class="new-entry" autocomplete="off">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Add a quote</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote" pattern=".{3,}" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('3 characters minimum')">

                <input type="text" placeholder="author" name="author" pattern=".{1,}" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('1 characters minimum')">

                <button type="submit" class="red-button">Add</button>
            </form>
            <footer>
                &copy; 2017
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>;
        <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using invalid ejs syntax. Assuming the code is written correctly on the backend, you need to add an equal sign to the opening ejs tag, otherwise the template doesn’t know to read the contents of the variable.

```
<%= user %>
```

Should give you the results you are looking for.

You can find more information about proper ejs syntax here: http://ejs.co/

Comment: this fixed my problem! Thanks!